# troubleshooting wrong postscript font name in photoshop

Tags: windows-10, fonts, adobe-photoshop, postscript

Can anyone give me some more tips on how to fix/troubleshoot postscript font names? We have several computers that run scripts in photoshop and on most, photoshop has a postscript font name of Trocchi. However on one of them, it has that same font as Trocchi-Regular instead which is an issue b/c we can't reuse the same scripts across the pcs.  I've tried uninstalling the font from the problematic computer and reinstalling it from a copy of the same font from another computer but it keeps showing Trocchi-Regular as the postscript name in photoshop.  I've installed FontForge and opened the font and confirmed that the fontname under PS Names is Trocchi and not Trocchi-Regular. (There was another version of this font that did have Trocchi-Regular as the PS Name in FontForge at one point but I deleted that one).  I've tried regedit and this font isn't even in there.

My script to get postscript names in photoshop

```
#target Photoshop

var str = "";
for(var i = 0;i<app.fonts.length;i++){
    var font = app.fonts[i];
    str = str+font.name +" : "+font.postScriptName + " -- ";
}

var doc = app.documents.add();

var layer = doc.artLayers.add();

layer.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
layer.textItem.kind = TextType.PARAGRAPHTEXT;
layer.textItem.size = 12;
layer.textItem.width = doc.width;
layer.textItem.height = doc.height;
layer.textItem.contents = str;
```

Thanks!